# How to save a configuration value programatically in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, configuration

I have been researching this for a few hours and all the sample code I found was not working on 2.4.x Can anyone share a snippet which I can run from the magento root and changes a certain configuration value. What I tried to use without success is:

```
<?php
    namespace Company\Integration\Model;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\Storage\WriterInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    class Data
    {
       protected $configWriter;
       public function __construct(WriterInterface $configWriter) {
           $this->configWriter = $configWriter;
       }
       /**
        * @param $path = 'porto_settings/product/page_layout'
        * @param $value = '2columns-left'
        */
       public function SetData($path, $value) {
            print $path;
            print $value;
            $this->configWriter->save($path, $value, $scope = ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT, $scopeId = 0);
       }
    }
?>
```